# Report Builder 3.0: changing cell background for an aggregate expression

Tags: expression, aggregate-functions, background-color, reportbuilder3.0

Hopefully this is an easy question.  I am working on a report containing an allocation sum for each person. I would like all allocation amounts greater than 100% to display with red background color, those that equal 100% to be green.  All other cells can remain clear with no background.

I right clicked the cell with the sum, selected text box properties, and then fill. I entered the following expression: `=IIF(Sum(Fields!Allocation.Value) =100%, "Green", IIF(Sum(Fields!Allocation.Value) >100%, "Red", "Transparent"))`

I do not receive an error message but no data shows in the total column. Its like the transparent took over the cells. I've been trying to figure this out for three days. Please help!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to the instance of the value in the report, instead of the field. So use `ReportItem![textbox name]` in your expression.

For example:

`IIF(ReportItems!TestScoreStudent.Value/ReportItems!TestMax.Value*100 < Parameters!Yellow.Value, "#f4a0a5", IIF(ReportItems!TestScoreStudent.Value/ReportItems!TestMax.Value*100 >= Parameters!Green.Value, "#b4eeb9", "#f4e5a9")))`